How To Get p Element Value Using Jsoup Library in Android Application
I want to get  element value from a website to be shown in my android app. I can get other values but when I try to get p element values , I get no result. How can I sort this out ?
Thanks in advance.
Html Code
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6  text-center">
        <h2 class="basliklar">ŞEHİRİÇİ</h2>
        <p id="sehiricino" class="no">32</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <h2 class="basliklar">ŞEHİRDIŞI</h2>
        <p id="sehirdisino" class="no">66</p>
      </div>
</div>

This is my code
private class siraBilgileri extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String URL = "https://www.********.com";
    String stringKisa, stringUzun;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = null;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            Elements elementsKisa = document.select("div[class=row]").select("div[class=col-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6  text-center]").select("p");
            Elements elementsUzun = document.select("div[class=row]").select("div[class=col-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6  text-center]").select("p");
            stringKisa = elementsKisa.text();
            stringUzun = elementsUzun.text();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        super.onPostExecute(unused);

        //TextViewlere Aktar
        tvKisaSonuc.setText(stringKisa);
        tvUzunSonuc.setText(stringUzun);
    }


According to the [jsoup] cookbook, looks like all you need is: Jsoup.parse(html).select("p")

The way you're querying is whitespace sensitive (an extra space between class names of an element in your Java code will not find the element that only uses a single space to separate class names in your input HTML).
Use the "dot-based" syntax to separate class names. Live example.
Something like this should work:
//Document document = ...;
Elements result = document.select("div.row > div.col-6.col-md-6.col-xs-6.text-center p");
stringKisa = result.get(0).text();
stringUzun = result.get(1).text();

